# MongoDB index direction on booleans

Tags: mongodb, indexing

When creating a MongoDB index, one needs to provide a direction for the field. The direction matters regarding the performance of a query, especially for compound index, because the engine knows it can stop looking for more result at some point.

When indexing booleans, does the direction matter ? Of course if it's a single index it can be read forward or backward, but when it's a compound one, I think it matters.

For instance, I have a collection with millions of entries, and I need to find those with a specific boolean value to `false`, and a timestamp field between 2 given dates (the timeframe is in the close past, like between a day ago and several minutes ago).
I thus need indexing both the boolean and the timestamp field. I thinks the most efficient way to do that is to index the boolean first, then the timestamp, because this way it can find the entries matching the boolean values, then read the timestamp until it becomes outside the needed timeframe (thank to the sorting)

So, knowing that I need only the `false` values and the timeframe in anti-chronological order, which direction do I index the boolean field to ?

```
{
  my_boolean_field: 1,
  my_timestamp_field: -1
}
```

or

```
{
  my_boolean_field: -1,
  my_timestamp_field: -1
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

It appears direction doesn't matter when indexing booleans.

A simple test, looking for fields with value equals to `true`, then to `false`, show that the index is always read in the `forward` direction :

```
db.collection.find({my_boolean_value: true}).explain()
```

or

```
db.collection.find({my_boolean_value: false}).explain()
```

both display `"direction" : "forward",` in the winningPlan.

Also when looking at the executionStats, the `keysExamined` matches the `nbReturned` field.